# jQuery using variable with string inside a selector

Tags: jquery

This code prints about 15 rows of data with this select box near each row.  I need to capture user's selected value for each row to send it of to the next function.  I'm receiving this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'val'.  Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
count = 1;
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    $('<div class="hd_field">Payment Format: <select name="Payment_Format" id="Payment' + count + '" class="Payment_Format"><option value="CTX" selected="selected">Company to Company</option><option value="PPD">Company to Person</option></select><div id ="Selected_Format' + count + '"></div></div>').appendTo(newDiv3);
    $('select#Payment' + count).change(function() {
        alert(this.val());
        PaymentFormat = $(this).val();
        element.PmtRec.PmtFormat = PaymentFormat;
        $('#Selected_Format' + count).text(PaymentFormat);
    });
    console.log(data);
    count = count + 1;
});​
```

Comment: Is the `data` variable an array?

Comment: Yes, its a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is thrown on this line:

```
$('select#Payment'+count).change(function() { 
    alert(this.val()); //Here
    //...
});
```

The problem is that in the `change` event handler, `this` refers to the actual DOM node, not a jQuery object, and the DOM node will not have a `val` method. You need to pass it to jQuery if you want to use `val`:

```
$('select#Payment'+count).change(function() {
    alert($(this).val()); //Pass `this` to jQuery
    //...
});
```

Comment: or change to `alert(this.value)`

Comment: Thank you that worked! But, the alert was just a test to see if the .change is working, the .text is still not doing anything.

Comment: Also, the object assignment isn't changing every time I select a different option.